# El pagination en bootstrap-table al cargar un solo registro no se muestra en donde debería, si se carga un nuevo registro se soluciona

Tags: nodejs, leaflet, bootstrap-table

Estoy trabajando con leaflet y debo seleccionar un polígono el cual cuenta con atributos, los cuales de deben mostrar en una tabla, pero siempre que cargo la tabla y selecciono el primer polígono carga los datos pero  el pagination no se ubica correctamente, al seleccionar un segundo polígono esto se soluciona. Este problema siempre sucede cuando se carga el primer registro y por css el primer registro no se muestra.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Código**

````
        console.log($("#table-container").height());
        $("#table").bootstrapTable('destroy').bootstrapTable({   
          cache: false,
          height:$("#table-container").height(),
          locale: "es-ES",
          undefinedText: "",
          // striped: false,
          pagination:true,
          buttonsClass: "btn-light",
          minimumCountColumns: 1,
          sortName: config.sortProperty,
          sortOrder: config.sortOrder,
          toolbar: "#toolbar",
          search: false,
          trimOnSearch: false,
          showColumns: true,
          showToggle: true,
          largeColumns:true,
          iconSize: 'sm',
          columns: table,
          mobileResponsive:true,
          smartDisplay: true,
          checkOnInit:true,
          pageList:"[10, 25, 50, 100, All]",
          onClickRow: function (row) {
            try{
              fitBounds(featureLayer.getLayer(row.leaflet_stamp).getBounds(), {padding: [50, 50]});
              highlightLayerRemove();
              highlightLayerAdd(featureLayer.getLayer(row.leaflet_stamp).feature);
              addToMap(highlightLayer);
            }catch{
              null;
            }
            
          },
          onDblClickRow: function (row) {
          // do something!
              null
          }
        });
        
        // map.fitBounds(featureLayer.getBounds());
        console.log(document.body.clientWidth)
        $(window).on("resize",function () {
            $("#table").bootstrapTable("resetView", {
              height: $("#table-container").height()
            });
        });
        if (document.body.clientWidth >= 100) {
          $("#table").bootstrapTable("refreshOptions", {
            pagination: true,
            showColumns: true,
            showToggle: true,
          });
        }else{   
          $("#table").bootstrapTable("refreshOptions", {
            pagination: true,
            showColumns: true,
            showToggle: true,
          });

          
        }
      } ```
````